# []string to jsonb with Gorm and postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, go-gorm

I have a Go struct which contains a slice of strings which I'd like to save as a jsonB object in Postgres with GORM.

I've come accross a solution which requires to use the GORM specific type (postgres.Jsonb) which I'd like to avoid.

When I try to run the AutoMigrate with a slice in my model, it panics and won't start although when I wrap this slice in a struct (which I'm okay doing) it will run without error but won't create the column in postgres.

```
type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Data []string `sql:"type:"jsonb"; json:"data"`
} //Panics
```

```
type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Data struct {
            NestedData []string
        } `sql:"type:"jsonb"; json:"data"`
} //Doesn't crash but doesn't create my column
```

Has anyone been able to manipulate jsonb with GORM without using the postgres.Jsonb type in models ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to use JSONB in Gorm is to use `pgtype.JSONB`.

Gorm uses `pgx` as it driver, and `pgx` has package called `pgtype`, which has type named `pgtype.JSONB`.

If you have already install `pgx` as Gorm instructed, you don't need install any other package.

This method should be the best practice since it using underlying driver and no custom code is needed. It can also be used for any JSONB type beyond `[]string`.

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Data pgtype.JSONB `gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'[]';not null"`
}
```

Get value from DB

```golang
u := User{}
db.find(&u)

var data []string

err := u.Data.AssignTo(&data)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
```

Set value to DB

```golang
u := User{}

err := u.Data.Set([]string{"abc","def"})
if err != nil {
    return
}

db.Updates(&u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
type DataJSONB []string

func (dj DataJSONB) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(dj)
}

func (dj *DataJSONB) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("[]byte assertion failed")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, dj)
}

// Your bit
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Data DataJSONB `sql:"type:"jsonb"; json:"data"`
}
```

Comment: I get this error: 
struct field tag `sql:"type:"jsonb";json:"studs"` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: key:"value" pairs not separated by spacesstructtag

Answer (score -1):

Define a new type:

```golang
type Data map[string]interface{}
```

And implement the `Valuer` and `Scanner` interfaces onto them, which allows the field to be converted to a *value* for the database, and *scanned* back into the field, respectively:

```golang
// Value converts into []byte
func (d Data) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  j, err := json.Marshal(d)
  return j, err
}

// Scan puts the []byte back into Data
func (d *Data) Scan(src interface{}) error {
  source, ok := src.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New("Type assertion .([]byte) failed.")
  }

  var i interface{}
  if err := json.Unmarshal(source, &i); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  *d, ok = i.(map[string]interface{})
  if !ok {
    return errors.New("Type assertion .(map[string]interface{}) failed.")
  }

  return nil
}
```

Then you can define your field in your model like this:

```golang
type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Data Data `type: jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb`
}
```

Using the underlying `map[string]interface{}` type is nice too, as you can `Unmarshal`/`Marshal` any JSON to/from it.

Comment: Does this still work? I have been trying this and I keep getting `panic: invalid sql type SomeMapType (map)`
I have an associated question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289749/invalid-sql-type-map-for-postgres?noredirect=1&lq=1