# invalid sql type (map) for postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, go-gorm

I'm trying to save a nested struct into postgres using gorm, but I'm hitting some issues with my `map[string]*InnerStruct` type.

I want to store my map type as JSONB in postgres, so I've defined a Scanner/Valuer like so as suggested in similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092840/string-to-jsonb-with-gorm-and-postgres):

```golang
type SomeMapType map[string]*InnerStruct

type StoreStruct struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id               string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    AccountID        string
    SomeMapType      SomeMapType `gorm:"column:cache,type:jsonb"`
}

var _ driver.Valuer = SomeMapType{}
var _ sql.Scanner = &SomeMapType{}

func (smt SomeMapType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(smt)
}

func (smt *SomeMapType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &smt)
}
```

but when I try to create a table like so:

```golang
err := db.
        CreateTable(StoreStruct{}).
        Table(tableName).Error)
```

A panic occurs:
`panic: invalid sql type SomeMapType (map) for postgres [recovered]`

It looks like this happens even before my Valuer/Scanner implementations are called.

Is it just not possible to store a `map` field on a struct you want to save to a DB with gorm?
I believe I've seen examples that seem to be working with `map[string]interface{}` so I'm not sure why my scenario is different?

Comment: Make sure to add a closing `"` to your struct tags for SomeMapType.

Comment: Yep, sorry lost the quote while anonymizing the code

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks that link isn't that relevant because it's not dealing with a `map[string]SomeType`, I'm able to implement Scanner/Valuer for other types fine.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was not including the SQL type tag annotation.

Making the changes below fixed my issue:

```golang
type StoreStruct struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id               string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    AccountID        string
    SomeMapType      SomeMapType `gorm:"column:cache" sql:"type:jsonb"`
}
```