# How to insert Data in JSONB Field of Postgres using GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have model like this in

- model.go

```
type yourTableName struct {
   Name             string `gorm:"type:varchar(50)" json:"name"`
   Email            string `gorm:"type:varchar(50)" json:"email"`
   FieldNameOfJsonb JSONB  `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"fieldnameofjsonb"`
}
```

- I want to insert FieldNameOfJsonb as an `array of object` in postgres using GORM
- Like given below

```
{
    "name": " james",
    "email": "james@gmail.com",
    "FieldNameOfJsonb": [
        {
            "someField1": "value",
            "someFiedl2": "somevalue",    
        },
        {
            "Field1": "value1",
            "Fiedl2": "value2",
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add this below code in Model.go ([referenceLink](https://coussej.github.io/2016/02/16/Handling-JSONB-in-Go-Structs/))

```
import (
    "errors"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
)

// JSONB Interface for JSONB Field of yourTableName Table
type JSONB []interface{}

// Value Marshal
func (a JSONB) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(a)
}

// Scan Unmarshal
func (a *JSONB) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b,&a)
}
```

-> reference Link for [Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

- now you can insert data using `DB.Create(&yourTableName)`

Comment: I would change the type to: `type JSONB map[string]interface{}`

Comment: obviously we can change as per our requirement

Answer (score 11):

I have answered a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636216/13719636 .

The simplest way to use JSONB in Gorm is to use `pgtype.JSONB`.

Gorm uses `pgx` as it driver, and `pgx` has package called `pgtype`, which has type named `pgtype.JSONB`.

If you have already install `pgx` as Gorm instructed, you don't need install any other package.

This method should be the best practice since it using underlying driver and no custom code is needed.

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Data pgtype.JSONB `gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'[]';not null"`
}
```

Get value from DB

```golang
u := User{}
db.find(&u)

var data []string

err := u.Data.AssignTo(&data)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
```

Set value to DB

```golang
u := User{}

err := u.Data.Set([]string{"abc","def"})
if err != nil {
    return
}

db.Updates(&u)
```

Comment: dsnt wok for me

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me either

Comment: any working solution for this?

Comment: Metadata         pgtype.JSONB `json:"-" gorm:"column:metadata"` helps.. "type:jsonb" was causing issue for me.. remove it and it works :)

Comment: thanks, it worked for me, my type was a slice of int, and used the same code as its above

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [gorm-jsonb](https://github.com/dariubs/gorm-jsonb) package.