# Storing an array of strings in postgresDB using golang gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, go-gorm

I am using golang gorm and Postgres in my project. I need to store the interests of group in array with but it stores in jsonb.

The Data i am trying to store looks like

```
["Boxing","Badminton","Basketball","Bowling"]
```

[image: My current DB]

```
type Group struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name      string `gorm:"size:255;not null" json:"groupName"`
}

type GroupDetails struct{
    ID          uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    GroupId     uint
    GroupUserIds pgtype.JSONB 
    GroupInterests  pgtype.JSONB 
}
```

A group id can have multiple userIds and groupInterests. Thats why i am making an array of group userIds and groupInterests.

Even changing the type from pgtype.JSONB doesnt help.
Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert Data in JSONB Field of Postgres using GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434115/how-to-insert-data-in-jsonb-field-of-postgres-using-gorm) Please also provide examples of how you are working with the data in Golang

Comment: Postgres [supports native arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), so you are not forced to use jsonb. Then use [`pq.StringArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray) as your struct field type.

Comment: @richyen , had to write a custom marshaller and Unmarshaller to make it work.